# Is it ok to build ViewCell in OnBindingContextChanged event?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have some custom ViewCell elements and most of them show and hide some components according to some properties of the BindingContext. I need to check values of some properties and show and hide some elements in the ViewCell, and also adjust the cell height accordingly.

Instead of writing value converters for most of the properties, I convert the BindingContext to underlying type and check the values of the properties in the OnBindingContextChanged event and right after that I build the UI with the relevant controls.

Do you think this is a bad way? Or is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

I think it sounds quite counter-intuitive with regards to the MVVM model. Would you not be best binding the IsVisible property of the controls to a property determined in the ModelView?

e.g.

```
var label = new Label();
label.setBinding<ViewModel>(Label.IsVisibleProperty, vm => vm.IsLabelVisible, BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

You can then control the value of the IsLabelVisible property within the ViewModel instance.

One gotcha to consider is draw cycles and I would advise wrapping elements with toggled visibility states in Layout class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DataTemplateSelector pattern (similar to WPF): 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/66502/#Comment_66502